# Intersection Between 2 lines in COCOS2D

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game using COCOS2D.
In my game, there are 4 points, each point is connected with each other by one line.
When user moves the point, the lines move with the point.
At the time of moving, if a line intersects with another line, line color should become red.
How can I do this, i.e. line to colored red?
And how to detect the intersection of two lines?
Can anyone help me to solve this intersection problem in COCOS2D?

Comment: Please fix your formatting - you obviously speak decent English, so there is no excise for your spelling and gramatical abominations.

Comment: @jrtc27: s/excise/excuse/ ;-P But I agree, a little bit more effort in providing a good question can be expected.

Answer (score 3):

You can detect whether 2 segments intersect using this function provided by cocos2d.

BOOL ccpSegmentIntersect(CGPoint A, CGPoint B, CGPoint C, CGPoint D)

Answer (score 1):

There's a question that could be considered a duplicate of your question but it's more generic:

[How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)

It has a few nice algorithms, though the answer that might be the most useful for you is the [answer from Gavin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect/1968345#1968345) as it provides a C function that you can easily adapt.